# variable type of Bit

Tags: sql, boolean, bit

I am getting values from a database table and saving them in their corresponding variable types.
I have a doubt regarding when I get BIT type data from a database(i.e True or False),
what type of datatype should I use to save it in .

E.g

```
public string Industry { get; set; }
        public bool CO2e { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
```

Here Industry and ID are string and int type respectivly. But the ISEFCO2e is a variable i am using for BIT type of data coming from the table.  So using bool with it would be correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx): The string values TRUE and FALSE can be converted to bit values: TRUE is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0.

Note that a bit may only hold 1 or 0. This is all you need to represent a boolean in a persistent way. Note thay for SQL-server in particular, the database will return "true" and "false", literally.

Comment: If I convert this bool type variable to string when I want to display it on a grid, will it show true,false or 0,1?

Comment: Well that may depend on which database engine you use. That's why I said SQL server returns `true` or `false` literally, when used in gridviews. Or it might make a checkbox. Anyway, don't worry, you will mostly not get 0 or 1. You can only find out by trying.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server and .NET, a BIT evaluates to a `bool` and vice versa. It will be displayed as true/false unless you specify otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

A bit just has two values which are 0/1 so a `bool` is the perfect match for such a value.